# What AppKit controls / components were used to create the iMovie/FCP timeline scrubber?

Tags: macos, appkit

I am interested in creating a video editor similar to iMovie on macOS. The scrubber is an interesting component, and I am wondering if anyone knows what control is used to create it.

My personal guess is that it is NSCollectionView.

[image: NSCollectionView?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a custom view. It is a subclass of TLKTimelineView called CETimelineView that is embedded in a custom scroll view called LKScrollView.
This makes sense as the video has to be in sync with the timeline, audio and video. Would require a highly optimized control. You can debug the view in xCode.

[image: iMovie debugged in xCode]

Comment: Tim, it appears you have more than two toes. Wishing you a belated "thank you" for your response, genuinely appreciate your words and the screenshot.

Comment: Awesome, how can you debug iMovie? It's impossible AFAIK.